# How can i access nested raw data services call json API data in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, api

I made a project to pull data from web service API. But the web service has nested arrays that needs to be displayed too, how can i access the data from nested JSON arrays?, what is the right way to write inside the HTML to get the data from the web service.

## API

```js
{
  "data": {
    "orders": {
      "total": 17,
      "data": [
        {
          "id": 10896,
          "createdAt": "2019-12-30T07:18:19.182Z",
          "amount": 6000,
          "dealer": {
            "company": {
              "name": "Wartspeed "
            }
          },
          "transactions": [
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {
              "stripe": {
                "status": "SUCCEEDED",
                "card": {
                  "funding": "unknown"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "stripe": {
                "status": "REQUIRES_PAYMENT_METHOD",
                "card": null
              }
            },
            {},
            {
              "createdAt": "2019-12-30T07:18:19.187Z",
              "code": "T"
            }
          ]
        },
```

## courseinfo.service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CourseinfoService {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    getAboutPosts(){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
    let ServerURL = 'https://qa.watspd.com/graphql';
     return this.http.post(ServerURL,{headers}).map(res => res );
    }  
}
```

## courseinfo.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CourseinfoService } from './courseinfo.service';
@Component({
selector: 'app-courseinfo',
templateUrl: './courseinfo.component.html',
})
export class CourseinfoComponent implements OnInit {
data:any;
constructor(private courseservice:CourseinfoService) { }
ngOnInit() {
this.courseservice.getAboutPosts().subscribe(res=>
{
console.log(res);
this.data=res;
}); }}
```

## courseinfo.component.html

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div *ngFor="let post of data">
<p>{{data.createdAt}}</p>
<p>{{data.amount}}</p>
<p>{{data.name}}</p>
</div>
</div>
```

## courseinfo.ts

```js
export class data{
id: number;
createdAt: string;
amount: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `ngOnInit` to:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
....
ngOnInit() {
 this.courseservice.getAboutPosts().pipe(
   // pluck the data array
   map(res => res.data.data),
   // transform the array into an array that we want
   map(data => data.map(info => ({ id: info.id, createdAt: info.createdAt, amount: info.amount, name: info.dealer.company.name }))),
).subscribe(res=>
  {
   console.log(res);
   this.data = res;
  }); 
}
```

We got `id, createdAt, amount, name` and now you can put them in the HTML like how you have it.

Comment: What does `console.log(res)` give?

Comment: Please check my code  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7npaxq

Comment: I got this as an error now `"Http failure response for https://qa.watspd.com/graphql: 0 Unknown Error"`. I was missing a bracket before the subscribe, I have edited my answer, it should propel you forward now.

Comment: Hi Ali, I have updated -  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7npaxq

Comment: I get an error, I don't think you can do `jsonp` like that, you have to use `this.http` instead of `this.jsonp`.